# Uso de if dentro de un exec() y muestra error de sintaxis

Tags: sql, servidor

Que tal buenos dias intento imprimir el valor de una variable dentro un exec() dependiendo de un if pero me marca errores de syntaxis.

```
DECLARE @VALOR1 INT
SET @VALOR1 = 1

EXEC ('
    IF ('+@VALOR1+' = 1) 
            print '+@VALOR1+'
        ELSE 
            SET '+@VALOR1+' = 2
            print '+@VALOR1+'
    END ')
```

alguien me pudiera ayudar? 
Gracias!
PD( la asignacion de valor1 a 2 es solo para ver que entra en el else.

Comment: no estás asignando `2` a `valor1`, tal y como está puesto se estará intentado asignar `2` al valor `1` (lo que te dará un error cuando se ejecute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en el `Else`:

```
DECLARE @VALOR1 INT
SET @VALOR1 = 1

EXEC ('
    IF ('+@VALOR1+' = 1) 
            print '+@VALOR1+'
        ELSE 
            SET '+@VALOR1+' = 2 //<-- Esta linea genera el error : Set 1 = 2
            print '+@VALOR1+'
    END ')
```

Por lo que te deberia quedar el codigo:

```
DECLARE @VALOR1 INT
SET @VALOR1 = 1

EXEC ('
    DECLARE @VALOR1 INT
    IF ( ' + @VALOR1 +' = 1)
        BEGIN
            print ' + @VALOR1 + '
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            print ' + @VALOR1 + '
        END' )
```

Ahora dentro de un `exec` no puedes asignar a las variables declaradas fuera del codigo ejecutado por el `exec` ya que se considera que son generadas por una sesion distinta y si pusieras :

```
SET @VALOR1 = ' + @VALOR1 + '
```

Te dara un error de variable @VALOR1 no declarada ya que no existe dentro de la sesion creada por el `exec`.

Saludos

Comment: gracias, me ayudaste bastante.